# React js filter selections

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react. I figured out how to make buttongroup act like multiselect, but I cannot figure out how to do that if at least one filter is selected, “All” would be unselected and if “All” is clicked, all filters are unselected, “All” then would be selected?

Here's what i currently have:
https://jsbin.com/xiwuyemeva/edit?js,console,output

```
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const ButtonGroup = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup;

class Options extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleOption = this.toggleOption.bind(this);
    this.getBsStyle = this.getBsStyle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selected: {
        A: false,
        B: false,
        C: false,
      }
    }
  }

  toggleOption(e) {
    const key = e.target.value; // e.g. 'A'
    const value = !this.state.selected[key];
    const newSelected = Object.assign(this.state.selected, {[key]: value});
    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
    console.log('this.state', this.state);
  }

  getBsStyle(key) {
   return this.state.selected[key] ? 'primary' : 'default';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='A' bsStyle={this.getBsStyle('A')}>
          All
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='B' bsStyle={this.getBsStyle('B')}>
          Option B
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='C' bsStyle={this.getBsStyle('C')}>
          Option C
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Options />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Any ideas or guidelines how i could handle those events would be really appreciated

Comment: don't give states for each button value. just state of selected value. and based on it get it's bsStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you, you wanted only one button style would be `primary`. every other will be `default`. then here is the normal solution i have provided.

```
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const ButtonGroup = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup;

class Options extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleOption = this.toggleOption.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selected: {
        A:true,
        B:false,
        C:false,
      }
    }
  }

  toggleOption(e) {
    const key = e.target.value;
    let selected = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.selected))
    if (key == 'A' && !selected.A) {
       selected.B = selected.C = false    
    }else if (key != 'A') {
      selected.A = false
    }
    selected[key] = !selected[key]
    this.setState({selected})
  }

  render() {
    const {selected} = this.state
    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='A' bsStyle={selected.A ? 'primary' : 'default'}>
          All
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='B' bsStyle={selected.B ? 'primary' : 'default'}>
          Option B
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleOption} value='C' bsStyle={selected.C ? 'primary' : 'default'}>
          Option C
        </Button>
      </ButtonGroup>
      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Options />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Demo : https://jsbin.com/topuwocosa/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I want to keep possibility to select Option B button + Option C button together, but i what i also want:
When "All" button would be clicked options B and C would deselect, and if Option B or C or them both together is selected "All" button would deselect

Comment: @Ntel i've updated answer. test it and let me know if is there any issue.

Comment: now when I select option B and option C and when i Click All button everything is good B and C options gets deselected.
but - when i select option B or/and option C , All button does not get deselected.

Comment: @Ntel isn't that a case? that if you select B/C after A is selected. A will be deselected. and selected key will be primary?

Comment: i removed "!" in if (key == 'A' && !selected.A) { line and now everything works fine, thank you

Comment: @Ntel try the current code again. it will work as expected.

Comment: i tried. I can now select Option B and Option C and when i click All button those B and C options deselects - working good.
But when i try to select one of those: Option B or Option C and then deselect one of them, it doesn't get deselected.

Comment: Ahh. that means you also want to deselect it by clicking again on that button?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want

Comment: one more question, i'm trying to play with IF statements but still cannot manage to resolve: When only one option is selected and it gets deselected, All button should get selected, what statement logic should i implement?

Comment: @abhishekchopda it should be based on your current requirements. this is built on Ntel's custom requirements, if you have something exact to do, this will work.